# Multiprocessing limited to two threads

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to read large files, feed them to a dictionary, and then rearrange to a different dictionary. Single threading is painfully slow, so I would like it to run each file simultaneously. My script only spawns two child processes, using only two threads

Edit: Added more of the code showing input arguments.

```
import multiprocessing

def process_reads(f, de):
    fdata = {}
    with open(f) as fp:
        for line in fp:
            if line[0] == '>': read = line
            elif len(line) >=3: fdata[read] = read+line
            else: continue  
    samples ={}
    for k,v in fdata.items():
        name = k.split()[0]
        name = name.split(de)[0]
        name = name.split('-')[0][1:].strip()
        if name in samples: samples[name].append(v)
        else: samples[name] = [v]
    return samples, str(f)

def main():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('-f',  '--file', nargs ='+', required=True, type=str, dest='in_file')
    parser.add_argument('-t',  '--threads', required=False, type=int, dest='threads', default=4)
    parser.add_argument('-d',  '--delimiter', required=False, dest='delim', default=' ')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    argument_list = args.in_file

    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=args.threads)
    sorted_f = [pool.apply_async(
        process_reads, 
        args=(file,args.delim, ),
        callback=None
    ) for file in args.in_file]
    pool.close()
    pool.join()
```

It doesn't matter how may processes I specify as var 'threads', it only runs two. I have never done multithreading so appreciate the help. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Please provide an example that sets values for `args.threads`, and `args.in_file`. Also, you appear to be missing a `pool.join()`? Just running some simplified code that does the same as yours works just fine for any number of threads, so it's likely an issue with the inputs/parameters

Comment: You hardly can parallelize IO operations on common hardware. You probably get on thread reading from disk and other processing data, all others are idle even if `len(in_file) > 2`.

Answer (score 0):

How many CPUs / cores do you have? You can `import os` and `print (len(os.sched_getaffinity(0)))` on most UNIX-like platforms to check how many processes are actually available to your script. You can also do processes = None, and Python will use your total CPUs (same number as os.cpu_count()).

By the way, multiprocessing and multithreading are different. You are using processes, with process_reads running asynchronously. If the main slow-down of your program is I/O bound (reading and writing the large files), multithreading is probably better for you, or a single-thread program with asyncio for the file operations. If your dictionary processing is the slow-down (CPU bound), you are correct that multiprocessing is the way to go within Python (threads won't help in that case, assuming you're using CPython).

Comment: I think it is an I/O issue. I have 36 threads/18 cores.

Answer (score 0):

You create a `Pool` with four workers.
But if `len(args.in_file)` is less than four, they will not all be used...

Also keep in mind that `multiprocessing.Pool` uses different *processes* to run code in. It only uses threads for some behind-the-scenes housekeeping.